# Group $N \triangleleft G$, $(|N|,|G/N|) = 1$, then $N$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, characteristic-subgroups

$N$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$. The orders of $N$ and $G/N$ are relatively prime. Prove that $N$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$.

I don't know what I can get from the second condition, can anyone give me some hints?

Answer (score 4):

**Outline:**

Take arbitrarily $\phi \in \text{Aut}(G)$. Call $K=\phi(N)$. Enough to show $K \subseteq N$ . Here $K$ is a subgroup and $N$ is normal, so $KN$ is also a subgroup and $KN/N \leq G/N$, so order of $KN/N$ divides the order of $G/N$ . Use [second isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems) to see order of $KN/N$ divides the order of $N$ also. Now use hypothesis to conclude $KN=N$ and hence $K \leq N$

Comment: Nice proof. +1 for it.

Comment: The order of $K/N\cap K$ divides the order of $K$, which is equal to the order of $N$, since $\varphi$ is an automorphism.

Comment: @awllower:  Actually i try to type the explanation to "the fox" but you done my job! Thanks !

Comment: @the_fox: thats what my title called **outline** !

Comment: @the_fox:  why so angry?  The reason for mentioning these type of answer is  **if the teacher helps too much, nothing is left to the student. So the teacher should help, but not too much and of course not too little, so that the student shall have a reasonable share of the work**.( Although I'm not a teacher. These words are said by Polya)

Comment: @the_fox: That is very different from saying that it is incorrect.

Comment: @the_fox I don't see why it is not clear to everyone that an automorphism preserves the order: an automorphism is by definition a bijection, and the order is by definition preserved by bijections. But I agree that adding **Observe that ...** can be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If $\psi$ is an automorphism of $G$:

Let $x \in N$. We're assuming the groups are finite so let $x^n = e$, so that $n$ divides $|N|$.

Moreover, $\psi(x)^m \in N$ for some $m$, or $x^m = e$ as well. $m$ divides $|G/N|$ but also $m$ divides $n$ - it must be that $m = 1$.

Comment: This is a nice proof, but it is not very clearly written (and not completely formally correct). What you are saying is that the order of $\psi(x)N$ divides both $[G:N]$ and the order of $\psi(x)$, which is equal to the order of $x$, and hence divides the order of $\lvert N\rvert$. It follows that the order of $\psi(x)N$ divides both $\lvert N\rvert$ and $[G:N]$, which are coprime, so $\psi(x)N$ is the identity, and hence $\psi(x)\in N$.

Comment: (This is essentially the same proof as in the other answer, but I think this presentation is potentially more clear.)